# Oldest Android OS version for basic functionality

Tags: android

I want to buy the most basic Android phone possible. Regarding the OS version, which is the oldest Android version that will still:

- get security updates for at least one year (essential)
- let me use common apps like Starbucks' app or McDonald's app (essential)
- Skype + Whatsapp, that is, run the updated version (essential)
- some basic but new game (this is a secondary need)

I assume that all will have a camera/video, a calender and let me take notes.

Comment: Older does not necessarily mean more basic. Some things have become more basic in recent versions. So, what is actually your need? Do you want the phone to be simpler? Less settings? More intuitive? Faster? Take less memory?

Comment: Welcome aboard, while you are on topic, asking for a software recommendation, are you aware of https://android.stackexchange.com/ for future questrions?

Comment: @Mawg: yes, but I thought this forum would be more inclined at providing an answer.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: I want it to be cheaper/cheapest, but still be able to perform the tasks listed above. That would imply needing less memory. I won't use many functions, so, it does not matter how intuitive/user friendly it is. Definitively no need for AI/Hey Google type of things.  Wi-Fi 802.11mc, facial recognition, etc.

Comment: Don't worry, there is nothing wrong with asking here. I would just have thought that there would be more Android gurus there, who might, for instance, know more about about long-term support. But we don't need them, because we have @Izzy :-)

Comment: Good news: All versions of Android are cheap, at exactly 0 EUR. It sounds like you want cheap hardware? In that case you should ask at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com Cheers!

Comment: If looking for the cheapest, then look on AliExpress, when you know what you are looking for. I ordered a dirt cheap (US $55, including postage) 10" Android 5.1 tablet there yesterday, but I only want mine for reading. Still, they will probably have the lowest new price, if you don't mind waiting; or consider eBay, CraigList, etc

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: I still need to know what OS version (as described above) will need the less hardware resources. That is, how far back in time can I go. I think I'll have to choose the Android first, then the hardware.

Comment: While Nicolas is technically correct, I agree with you :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: notice that the good folks in hardwarerecs could well send me here to ask.

Comment: @Mawg: I'll look at aliexpress after someone answers how low can the Android OS version be. I have seen similar cheap devices but was wary they could be almost-out-of-the-market kind of thing.

Comment: They might know a very cheap and old phone that was released with an old Android, but on which a recent Android can be installed.

Comment: I will tell you that you probably won't ever be able to upgrade the o/s, at least I couldn't with those cheap ones that I bought over the years